# Getting elements to change color individually

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to make a program that will basically change color when each element is clicked individually. I've got it to work to the point where I can click on just an the page and both of the elements can change color but I need them to be independent of each other. How would I do something like this?

```
document.onload = function()
{
    document.onclick = changeTest("box0", "green");
};

function changeTest(id, color)
{
    var element;
    element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

**Html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>this will appear on the tab in the browser</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="onclick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
{
border: 0;
margin:0;
paddig: 0;
}
body
{
font-family:"Times New Roman"; serif;
font-size: 12pt;
}
.box
{
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 2px;
}
#box0
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#box1
{
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="box" id="box0"></div>
    <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your html look like ? This is not enough.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting it...

Comment: Yeah im sorry. I didnt realize I entered it wrong. My mistake.

Comment: It will not resolve your issue but, you got an error around `* { border : 0; margin : 0; paddig : 0; }`. You wrote "paddig" instead of "padding".

Comment: Why does it matter what you have learned. If you get the correct answer you have taught yourself a new skill. I am doubtful the teacher has placed limits on learning...

Comment: Because I wouldn't understand the context of the action listener. He doesn't want us to write code we don't understand/hasn't taught us yet. I feel like this problem isn't something that is easily done though.

Comment: I agree with @user2009653. Learning new things is great, but using something you don't fully understand just to answer the problem doesn't help you. I think Zeratop's answer below solves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var box0 = document.getElementById("box0");
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");

var color = "green";

function changeColor(box, color) {
  box.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

box0.onclick = function() {
  changeColor(this, color);
};

box1.onclick = function() {
  changeColor(this, color);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>this will appear on the tab in the browser</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="onclick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        border: 0;
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      body {
        font-family:"Times New Roman"; serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
      }
      
      .box
      {
        height: 10em;
        width: 10em;
        margin: 2px;
      }
      
      #box0 {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      
      #box1 {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box" id="box0"></div>
    <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Knowing you can also perfom this with [addEventListener()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) method.

Comment: Based on the comment on the questions below this is the best possible answer. However, it does not support IE8 or 7 so it should be noted if you want that use [attachEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @CayceK is truely right, to enable cross version compatibility, you need to use `.onclick = function() { /* process */ }`, and if this is an excercice you should not use `.addEventListener()` if it is not the aim.

Comment: @user2009653 ... can you use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Post updated, I used the attachEvent like you would, but remember addEventListener !

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind the event listeners to the individual boxes. It's as simple as that. Something like this (not tested):

```
document.getElementById("box0").onclick = changeTest("box0", "green");
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = changeTest("box1", "green");
```

Comment: I've already tried that solution. The problem is that the program is currently running that code onload instead of onclick. So when you do click it nothing happens because it already ran it onload.

Comment: Yeah, I think it should have been `.onclick = function() { changeTest(...) }`. See @Zeratops answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery for that:

html:

```
<body>
<div class="box" id="box0">box0</div>
<div class="box" id="box1">box1</div>
</body>
```

and Script:

```
 $( "#box0" ).click(function() {
   changeTest("box0", "green");
});

$( "#box1" ).click(function() {
    changeTest("box1", "red");
});
```

Here's an jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/o8c8y23x/

Ok, without jquery:

```
<body>
  <div class="box" id="box0" onclick = "changeTest('box0', 'red');">box0</div>
  <div class="box" id="box1" onclick = "changeTest('box1', 'green');">box1</div>
</body>
```

jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/o8c8y23x/2/

Comment: I'm an intro programming course and Jquery is something completely out of the scope of what we are learning at the moment.